# Zend framework 1 and xdebug url

Tags: php, zend-framework, xdebug

1) I have problem when i want to make url Xdebug run on Zend framework 1: 
/mySite/index/index?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=sublime.xdebug

But when i run that code, zend router will convert my url to: 
/mySite/index/index/XDEBUG_SESSION_START/sublime.xdebug

I want they keep my original url: /mySite/index/index?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=sublime.xdebug

2) I just install SublimeXdebug, that's ok, but when i run, they make firefox is a default browser, how can i tell them run chrome instead of firefox? (i remember they config at python, but i don't know python)?

How i can solve that problem? Please help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use the browser extension for Firefox or Chrome to initiate your debugging sessions. that way, you don't have to change your URL at all. You can find the browser extensions through http://xdebug.org/docs/remote#browser-extensions